# Output returning characters

Tags: java, tree

I implemented the LCA algorithm after referring some sources online on SOF. And the output is coming out to be some characters as shown below. Could anyone please explain what's going wrong in my code below?

```
package trees;

public class LowestCommonAncestorBinaryTree {

    static class Node {
        Node left;
        Node right;
        int value;

        public Node(int value) {
            left = null;
            right = null;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
    // Source for below method : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056068/finding-least-common-ancestor-in-binary-tree
    public static Node findLca(Node node, int t1, int t2) {
        if(node == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if(node.value > t2 && node.value > t1) {
            // both targets are left
            return findLca(node.left, t1, t2);
        } else if (node.value < t2 && node.value < t1) {
            // both targets are right
            return findLca(node.right, t1, t2);
        } else {
            // either we are diverging or both targets are equal
            // in both cases so we've found the LCA
            // check for actual existence of targets here, if you like
            return node;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /**
         * Create a sample Binary Tree. A Binary tree does not have to maintain
         * left <root < right relationship.
         */
        Node root = new Node(1);
        root.left = new Node(2);
        root.right = new Node(4);
        root.left.left = new Node(6);
        root.left.right = new Node(5);

        root.right.left = new Node(9);
        root.right.right = new Node(11);
        root.right.right.left = new Node(7);
        root.right.right.right = new Node(3);


        System.out.println("Lowest Common Ancestor of Node 3 and 9 is: "
                + findLca(root, 3,9));


    }

}
```

Here is the output I am getting : 
Lowest Common Ancestor of Node 3 and 9 is: trees.LowestCommonAncestorBinaryTree$Node@6d06d69c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just didn't define `toString()` for your class `Node`. The string `"trees.LowestCommonAncestorBinaryTree$Node@6d06d69c"` is generated by the default `toString()`.

You can change the line printing result into:

```
System.out.println("Lowest Common Ancestor of Node 3 and 9 is: "
            + findLca(root, 3,9).value);
```

Comment: Alternatively, I can also override toString() method somewhere ?

Comment: Yes, override in class Node.