# Python: recursion in finding common ancestor in binary search tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have been looking at the pasted code below in the *Discuss* tab of Leetcode and I feel I don't fully understand recursion.  The [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-binary-search-tree/description/) is about finding the common ancestor of 2 nodes in a binary search tree.

```
def lowestCommonAncestor(self, root, p, q):
    if p.val < root.val > q.val:
        return self.lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, p, q)
    if p.val > root.val < q.val:
        return self.lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, p, q)
    return root
```

Could explain to me how `root` is changed such that it gives the answer without its value being updated? I see `root` being passed into the main function (an argument like `p` and `q`) but the recursive calls only take `root.left` and `root.right`.

Could you clarify the recursion with an explanation of finding the common ancestor of 3 and 5?

```
        _______6______
       /              \
    ___2__          ___8__
   /      \        /      \
   0      _4       7       9
         /  \
         3   5
```

The Stackoverflow accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056068/finding-least-common-ancestor-in-binary-tree) uses recursion but doesn't answer my question.

Where I found the code: https://leetcode.com/problems/lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-binary-search-tree/discuss/64963/3-lines-with-O(1)-space-1-Liners-Alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start at the root of the tree, and `p` and `q` are the nodes you want to get their common ancestor.

For you example, when `p` is the node 3, and `q` is the node 5. The `root` is 6.

So `p.val < root.val > q.val` will hold, and now you will call `self.lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, p, q)`.  You are just moving references of objects between functions.

Now your root will be `2` (the left of root), and `p` and `q` are the same. Now, `if p.val > root.val < q.val` will hold, because `3 > 2` and `5 > 2`, so we will call `self.lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, p, q)`. When we put the argument `root.right`, this is just a reference to a different object. Just to clarify, this does not change the value of any object, but it changes the value of `root` within the scope of the current function.

Now your root will be `4`, and none of the conditions will hold, so you will return `4` as your common ancestor.

Comment: if I am passing references, how is it that `root` is not `6` (if the root isn't changed) but `4`? I didn't think the `root` was changed so I was expecting `6` but the value returned is `4`.

Comment: the value of each individual object doesn't change, but when you pass `root.left` to the function as an argument, you pass a reference to `root.left`, then the `root` in your new function will be the `root.left` of your previous root. the `root` in each function call will be different.

Comment: I think I get it. You keep calling the function when the root value isn't between the values of `p` and `q`. When you get to the situation where it is, you return the root value of that specific function call [since you skipped the `if` statements]. The returned value gets relayed back to the main function call that initiated the recursion and because this first main call has a `return` statement, it returns that value and doesn't get to the last `return root` statement so the `root` remains the same [`6`] but the value returned is of the node that satisfied the condition i.e. `4`.

Answer (score 1):

Those `if` statements check if `q` and `p` are on the same side with respect to `root`.

First `if`'s meaning: both `p` and `q` are smaller than root, so they're on the left side. So, `root` is not their `lowestCommonAncestor`. For example, `3` and `5` in your example tree. They fall into this case. They are both lower than `6`, so their common ancestor is somewhere within the left part of main tree. Proceed to next step with `lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, p, q)`.

Second: Same as first, except, they're now on the right side. They are both greater than `root`, so they must have a `lowestCommonAncestor` somewhere in `root.right`.

This function proceeds until, there is such a case that, `p` and `q` are not on the same side anymore. In this case, `root` is the `lowestCommonAncestor`.

Comment: Yilmaz, the progression makes sense but what doesn't is how the returned value of `root` is `4` and not `6` if the `root` value is not explicitly updated.

Comment: `root` is not kept constant. As you proceed to new function, your new root is either `root.left` or `root.right`. You can see it by adding a `print("root: " + root)` on the first line of function.